# Geomapping with GeoPandas and Folium: Start Zoomed In and Add Marker

Tags: python, mapping, geopandas, folium

I'm using geopandas and folium mapping for the first time to try groups across the UK. I want my map to:

1. start zoomed in closer to the points of reference (and not have to scroll into the sites)
2. add a marker at a particular longitude/latitude to signify a hospital

Any tips appreciated, thanks!

My code is:

```
    for layer in map_layers:
        if layer == "high_users":
            if not high_users_processed:
                print("processing high users layer .. ")
                dyn_map = high_users.explore(
                    explore_col, 
                    m=folium.Map(location=[high_users.geometry.y.mean(), high_users.geometry.x.mean()], zoom_start=10),
                    legend=True,
                    cmap="cool"
                )
```

but I'm getting the error "ValueError: y attribute access only provided for Point geometries".

The code originally worked when "m=dyn_map" but I couldn't see how to add the marker or start zoomed in with the code like that.

Comment: `start zoomed in closer to the points of reference (and not have to scroll into the sites)` - Do you mean when the map is initially rendered on the view, it should show from some point of reference? Would you happen to know the point of reference from where you would like to show your map?